# How to render a DAE (COLLADA) file in Xcode 10.1. Currently crashing

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit

I am using Xcode 10.1 on OSX High Sierra 10.13.6 and I get one of two thing happen when I view a DAE (COLLADA) file in Xcode.

1. The document is not presented with the skin or clothing. I can only see the mesh or skeleton
2. Xcode unexpectedly quits.

I am working on displaying the DAE document on OSX, not iOS.  In the case where Xcode does not quit, the scene it not presented correctly.  I have ensured, looking at the debugging view that I can turn off the wiremesh and skeleton but character is not presented.

I have ensured, by looking at the debugging view turning off the wiremesh and skeleton but character is not presented.  I find that the files are also not presented correctly in Preview, which I find really strange.  My first thought is the file is corrupt however, I have exported DAE fies from MakeHuman, Blender and Mixamo.  I'm having a hard time believing all three programs are producing corrupt files.  The MakeHuman file caused Xcode to terminate but are viewable in Preview without textures.  Blender and Mixamo, do not terminate but will only show mesh and skeleton in Preview, Xcode and a SceneKit Scene.

I have downloaded files that do not render properly.

After research I thought that maybe the scntool located in (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/scntool) would fix the file but unfortunately it does not.

**Is there a tool or process to fix the files so they render properly and not terminate Xcode.**  What do I need to do to make this work properly.

The only files that have rendered properly are "idleFixed.dae" and "twist_danceFixed.dae" located here https://github.com/eh3rrera/ARKitAnimation

https://github.com/eh3rrera/ARKitAnimation/blob/master/ARAnimation/art.scnassets/idleFixed.dae (this works in Preview and Xcode)

https://github.com/eh3rrera/ARKitAnimation/blob/master/ARAnimation/art.scnassets/twist_danceFixed.dae (this also works)

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand but the crashing completely stopped after I updgraded from High Sierra to Mojave (10.14.2). No changes were made to Xcode.  It just stopped terminating when I viewed DAE files.

Its hard to believe that a fundamental part of Xcode, the viewing of DAE files for 3D management, would just not work.  I really thought there must be something wrong with the files and I just could not figure it out.

Comment: Glad it was fixed for you. Unfortunately the whole 3D component of Xcode is not given the same attention as the other components.